# Position of ImageView in ViewHolder returns 0 using .getLeft(). How do I get the position of an ImageView inside a ViewHolder

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the position of an ImageView inside a recycler viewholder however both `.getLeft()` and `.getTop()` are returning 0. How do I get the position on an ImageView Inside a ViewHolder?

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: Left: " +  viewHolder.vhUploadedPicture.getLeft());
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: Top: " + viewHolder.vhUploadedPicture.getTop());

        //Returning 0

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try measure coordinates of ImageView with this code:

```
viewHolder.vhUploadedPicture.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int[] coordinates = new int[2];
            viewHolder.vhUploadedPicture.getLocationOnScreen(coordinates); // or getLocationInWindow(coordinates)
            int imageLeft = coordinates[0];
            int imageTop = coordinates[1];
        }
    }
);
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to rename this variable. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [ViewTreeObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver) here.

```
view.getViewTreeObserver()
      .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(() -> {
        view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        //your measurements here
      });
```

Comment: This still returns 0 for both ```.getTop()```  and ```.getLeft()```